# Design pattern to solve event mess in Electron apps with ipcMain and ipcRenderer

Tags: node.js, design-patterns, electron

Because Electron has two processes our javasript code is not global, so I find myself sending and receiving a lot of events (with a lot of different names) to do something that we usually do with just a callback in the same method.
This is even worse if we need to share some global var (for example global constants).

My current approach is try to manage the connection between Main and Renderer as a websocket, but it does not feel so good and maybe I'm doing it wrong (also I feel I'm falling in DRY principle because I cannot create a global event listener with ipc, I need to hardcode the event name for every "send" and for every "on").
I'm managing the windows (Renderer process) as a View from MVC.
Maybe I should use the main process only to init the main window and then do everything (database, external api calls, etc) from our window (Renderer)? (that is, MVC all in Renderer process, and do almost nothing in Main process?)

What is a good design pattern to solve this two processes thing from Electron?

Answer (score 2):

> This is even worse if we need to share some global var (for example
>   global constants).

You can use the [global object](https://electronjs.org/docs/faq#how-to-share-data-between-web-pages)

```
require('electron').remote.getGlobal('sharedObject').someProperty = 'new value'
```

> I need to hardcode the event name for every "send" and for every
>   "on").

Not exactly a design pattern but my solution to this has been to define "routing" functions.

**Renderer:**

```
function sendMessageToMain(msg) {
    var arg;
    switch (msg) {  
        case "save-project":
            arg = { event: "save-project", sender: "editor", data: editorJson };

            break;
    }    
    ipcRenderer.send('app-message', arg);
 }
```

---

**Main:**

```
ipcMain.on('app-message', (event, arg) => {

    switch (arg.event) {
        case "save-project":
            global.model.data = arg.data;

            switch (arg.sender) {
                case "editor":
                    // do something
                    break;
                case "player":
                    // do something else
                    break;
            }
            break;
       }
}
```

Comment: I was trying to do something similar, nice workaround to send the event name as part of the data

Answer (score 0):

```
    // args = { route : 'some_function_name', ..... }
class ipc{
     constructor() {
        ipcMain.on('data', (event, args) => {
            let route = args.route
            if (this[route]) {    /* it looks given function name if 
                                      exist on class instance */
                this[route](args) // then call it
            } else return
        })
     }
     some_function_name(args){
          // codes
     }
}
```

> more specific solution about this

```
export default class ipcHelper {
    private parse_sender
    constructor() {
        ipcMain.on('data', (event, args) => {
            let route = args['route'] 
            if (this[route]){  // same as before , it look if 
                                      //function if exist in class 
                                          // instance
                this.parse_sender = (function (argsToSend) {
                    if (argsToSend['backToSender'])
                    {
                        event.sender.send('data' , argsToSend)
                    }
                    else return
                }(this[route](args))) /*self caller function
                                       it will call event.sender.send() 
            } 
        })
    }

}
```

> usage

```
class ipc extends ipcHelper{

      constructor() {
         super()
      }

      some_function_name(args) {
          // do stuffs here
          return let argsToSend = {
                                 backToSender : true, /* if you 
                                 don't want to send any data to 
                                 renderer, you should make it false */
                           // rest of other datas to send renderer
                              }
      }

}
```

Comment: It is always better to give some explanation of the code rather than just dumping the code. Or at-least have enough comments in the code that it is self explanatory.